# How to Assign Datgrid ItemSource from Parent DatGrid Selected Item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a Datagrid and inside it's row details template I have another Datagrid

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGridWorkOrders" ItemsSource="{StaticResource workorders}" >
<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
        <Border BorderThickness="0" Background="BlanchedAlmond" Padding="10">
        <DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Element=dataGridWorkOrders,path=selectedItem}">
  </DataGrid>
 </Border>
```

Workorders Collection is like:

```
class WorkOrders : ObservableCollection<WorkOrder>
    {
        public WorkOrders()
        {
            var orderList = OrderDetailsProvider.GetOrders() as List<WorkOrder>;

            orderList.ForEach(
                        order => this.Add(order));
        }
```

The WorkorderClass has following fields exposed as proporties.

```
 private string orderID;
 private int totalQuantity;
 private string status;
 private ObservableCollection<Schedule> scheduleCollection;
```

Now in my second datagrid I want to bind to **ScheduleCollection** of the currently selected datagrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data context of the `RowDetailsTemplate` should be the selected item -- so you should just bind to `scheduleCollection`:

```
<DataGrid IsReadOnly="true" ItemsSource="{Binding scheduleCollection}">
```

(... and either use `AutoGenerateColumns="true"`, or add the [`DataGridColumns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtextcolumn%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) manually)